# Format for vcalendar for weeks and day of week

Tags: google-calendar-api, iso8601, rfc5545

I generate a vcalendar file with DTSTART and DTEND with week numbers and day of week just like RFC5545 and ISO.8601.2004 [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) says. Like so:

```
DTSTART:2015W437T200000Z
DTEND:2015W437T210000Z
```

or

```
DTSTART:2015-W43-7T200000Z
DTEND:2015-W43-7T210000Z
```

Which read year 2015 week 43 day 7 (Sunday) 8.00pm to 9.00pm.

But neither google-calendar nor an online validator I've come across says that it's correct. Anyone got an idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Calendar API docs state](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts#timed_events), the format does not take weeks; instead, it uses [RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) and should read

```
DTSTART:2015-10-25T20:00:00Z
DTEND:2015-10-25T21:00:00Z
```

Comment: Your absolutely right. How could I miss that? I found a document that stated ISO8601 but that was obviously wrong. Anyway. Thanks. I'd vote up your answer if I could but I have to few points for that.

Comment: @bengan Never mind. If it helped you, you should be able to accept the question :)